# Terraform, local-exec, print output to console

Tags: terraform

I'm looking for a way to see output of a command executed in `local-exec`. I can easily forward it to a file but I need it to be visible in `terminal` during deployment. Is it possible?

This is part my resource file:

```
resource "azurerm_iothub" "service" {
  name                = "iot-hub-qnsie"
  resource_group_name = "my_rg_group"
  location            = "USA"


  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az iot hub device-identity create --device-id 'machine1' --edge-enabled --hub-name 'hub1'  --query 'deviceId'"
  }
```

Comment: The stdout may be logged at debug level or lower.

Comment: Yes it is logged, you can redirect that to a file easily. But the tricky part is to print it as terraform `output`

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that the output of the create command is the resource definition, you could do the following:

```
resource "azurerm_iothub" "service" {
  name                = "iot-hub-qnsie"
  resource_group_name = "my_rg_group"
  location            = "USA"


  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az iot hub device-identity create --device-id 'machine1' --edge-enabled --hub-name 'hub1'  --query 'deviceId'"
  }
}

data "external" "azurerm_iothub_devices" {
  depends_on = [azurerm_iothub.service]  # Wait until the resource was created in the previous step
  program = ["/bin/bash -c ", "az iothub device-identity show --hub-name 'hub1' --device-id 'machine1' --resource-group your-resource-group"]
}
```

While this does not directly read the output of the local-exec, you still have a possibility to load whatever was changed by the local exec. You can then access the values with: `data.external.azurerm_iohub_devices.(path-to-desired-property`

**Attention: The output of the program must be valid json, otherwise it cannot be accessed.**

Note that I could not test the command, but I have this structure running (just with different resources).

**Resource dependent specific improvement**:
If you create/update a resource with the exec-local which has a representation in a terraform resource, use this instead of data "external" as it makes parsing easier.